# $web.RootFolder.WelcomePage doesnt work on publish site

Tags: powershell, publishing-site, welcome-page

I need to change my default page of my site :

```
$assignment = Start-SPAssignment

    $web.RootFolder.WelcomePage ="Pages/"+ $page
    $web.RootFolder.Update()
    Stop-SPAssignment $assignment
```

But the welcome page still the same. 
My site is publish site, is there another solution .

Comment: Try `$web.RootFolder.WelcomePage = $page`. Assuming `$page` is the url of the page (ie. `default.aspx`). Not sure if it will pick up pages from `Pages` library, but this definitely works for `Site Pages`.

Comment: Yes it works fine for Teamsite  , but not on publish site .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said that you are working with a publishing enabled site. As far as I know, the code you are using can't work on Publishing sites, you should use the `.DefaultPage` property  provided by the `PublishingSite` class instead.

Try something like this:

```
$publishingWeb = 
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web);

// note: pageFile is the acuall SPFile for the page, not just the url.
$publishingWeb.DefaultPage =$pageFile; 
$publishingWeb.Update();
```

Notice that you have to get a `PublishingWeb` first - think of it like a sort of wrapper that extends the normal `SPWeb` object and provides new functionalities specific for publishing enabled web sites.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that everytime you instantiate $web.RootFolder it grabs a new object form the DB so your call to .Update() is actually doing nothing.

Try the following code:

```
$folder = $web.RootFolder
$folder.WelcomePage = "Pages/" + $page
$folder.Update()
```

This should work.

Comment: Still the same !